# Why is my `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`?

Tags: networking, sysctl

I just discovered accidentally that `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns 1. I can't remember having enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward` anytime ago, but since my system runs for several years now, I can't exclude that either.

I don't expect my `4.14.3-1-ARCH` having `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` by default, so in what place could this be enabled? I know about `/etc/sysctl.d`, but none of the files in there specifies IP forwarding. It is persistent across reboots, though, so where could it have been enabled? Thanks!

**Edit:** My Interfaces are:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:34:d9:a2:33:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:ee:75:8e:ef:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: pan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:02:14:5b:d8:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**Edit 2:** Contents of my `filter`-iptable:

```
# iptables -t filter -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Edit 3:** I stumbled upon a connection called `pan1` in NetworkManager, which is always connected and probably corresponds to the network interface `pan1`. Interestingly, it is in `bridge`-mode. Unfortunately, I can't imagine having created this connection by hand, and I can't find where it comes from (`grep -rn "pan1" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` gives no output). My first suspect, removing all paired bluetooth devices, brought no avail. Here's the connection's contents:

```
$ nmcli connection show pan1
connection.id:                          pan1
connection.uuid:                        fc8c690c-3874-48df-8ccb-98a0fc698604
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        bridge
connection.interface-name:              pan1
connection.autoconnect:                 no
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1512614672
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      100
ipv4.addresses:                         10.228.230.1/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            ignore
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      100
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
bridge.mac-address:                     --
bridge.stp:                             no
bridge.priority:                        32768
bridge.forward-delay:                   0
bridge.hello-time:                      1
bridge.max-age:                         19
bridge.ageing-time:                     299
bridge.group-forward-mask:              0
bridge.multicast-snooping:              yes
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           pan1
GENERAL.UUID:                           fc8c690c-3874-48df-8ccb-98a0fc698604
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        pan1
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/62
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.228.230.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.228.230.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

Comment: Does this help: `grep -rn net.ipv4.ip_forward /etc/*`

Comment: What kind of local networking interfaces and features do you have? NATs ? Bridges? etc.

Comment: @RubberStamp: Good idea, should have come to that myself. Unfortunately, it results in no output, so none of the files in /etc/ specify `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. @patrick-mevzek I've added my interfaces to my above post.

Comment: Do you have anything installed that could want to route packets like a virtualisation solution (vms or containers)? A fancy firewall management interface? hotspot to share your mobile 4g of wifi?

Comment: Are there any entry in the FORWARD chains of the `filter` iptables table? If any their names could give an indication as to what enabled forwarding.

Comment: Systemd uses the `IPForward` option to turn on `ip_forward` ... so you may want to search your systemd unit files:  `grep -rn IPForward /etc/*`

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas No such software, to my belief. Only NetworkManager. I've updated my question with the output of `iptables -t filter -L`. It is empty (I guess). @RubberStamp Unfortunately, `grep -rn IPForward /etc/*` doesn't return any output as well...

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas I may have finally found some trace, see the edit of my question.